Is Python function immutable?
I have
import copy
class A:
   _member_a: dict[str, str]
   _member_b: Callable

   def set_b(self, func):
       self._member_b = func

   def deep_copy(self):
       return copy.deepcopy(self)

I can set the value of _member_b with something like:
a = A()
a.set_b(some_actual_function_in_other_files) 

and in another file, I have:
def some_actual_function_in_other_files(self):
    # Implementation

def some_actual_function_in_other_files_2(self):
    # Implementation

so in my test, I wrote:
def test(self):
   a = A()
   a._member_a = {"test", "test"}
   
   a.set_b(some_actual_function_in_other_files)
   
   copy = a.deep_copy()
   self.assertIsNot(a._member_a, copy._member_a)  # pass, because dictionary is mutable and deepcopy is not using the same reference
   self.assertIsNot(a._member_b, copy._member_b)  # fail, which means `a._member_b` and `copy._member_b` shares the same reference

I understand in copy.deepcopy(), if the object is immutable, Python just use copy the reference(e.g., integers). So in this case, is _member_b immutable?
I believe so, because later I updated the copy._member_b and I found a._member_b still has the original value which means it's not affected by the change of the copy. Is it true?

“because later I updated the copy._member_b and I found a._member_b still has the original value which means it's not affected by the change of the copy.“ It sounds like you just overwrote the reference to a value, which is something you can do regardless of the value being referenced. For example, ints are immutable, but you can do a = 1 and then a = 2 no problem. Dicts are mutable, but a = b = {} and b = {"foo": "bar"} doesn’t set a.

Functions are mutable, but deepcopy() doesn't know how to make a copy of a function, so it just copies the reference.

@Ry- The real issue is the result of self.assertIsNot(a._member_b, copy._member_b) which fails.

@Barmar @Ry Does this mean if I want to have a deepcopy for my class A, I need to implement it myself rather than directly using copy.deepcopy()? I would like to have the ability to construct a deep copy of an instance of class A, and the new copy is completely independent from the original one.

deepcopy() already knows how to make a copy of your class instance. But even if you customize it, how would you make a copy of the function? There's nothing that does that.

While it's possible to mutate functions, you should generally treat them as immutable. What are you doing that needs to mutate the function?

@Coolboy What actually is the problem here? Why does the result of copy.deepcopy not work for you needs, precisely?

@Barmar okay thanks. I think I might be good with it, because my original thought is that I want to have the ability to create a completely independent copy, and I can play with the copy without any risk that modifies the original. I think copy.deepcopy() is enough for me, because I don't think there is any way to modify a function plus as Barmar said, there is no way for me to make a deep copy of the function anyway even if I want to customize it, so I think I am good with copy.deepcopy()

@juanpa.arrivillaga okay thanks. I think I might be good with it, because my original thought is that I want to have the ability to create a completely independent copy, and I can play with the copy without any risk that modifies the original. I think copy.deepcopy() is enough for me, because I don't think there is any way to modify a function plus as Barmar said, there is no way for me to make a deep copy of the function anyway even if I want to customize it, so I think I am good with copy.deepcopy()

What kind of "customizing" would you do that makes this difference matter? If you replace the function with a different one, or wrap it in a decorator, that's replacing the reference with a reference pointing to a different object, not updating the previous function in-place, so worrying about shallow vs deep copying isn't relevant.

Normal functions are mutable in Python, but copy.deepcopy doesn’t copy them anyway:

This module does not copy types like module, method, stack trace, stack frame, file, socket, window, or any similar types. It does “copy” functions and classes (shallow and deeply), by returning the original object unchanged; this is compatible with the way these are treated by the pickle module.

import copy

def func():
    pass

func2 = copy.deepcopy(func)
func.is_mutable = True   # no error
print(func2.is_mutable)  # True, not copied
print(func is func2)     # True, not copied


Does this mean if I want to have a deepcopy for my class A, I need to implement it myself rather than directly using copy.deepcopy()? I would like to have the ability to construct a deep copy of an instance of class A, and the new copy is completely independent from the original one.

@Coolboy: What exactly are you worried about? Unless you're setting attributes on the function (extremely rare), or relying on terrible things like mutating a mutable default argument as some sort of weird state-preserving persistent state (good God, no!), copying means nothing to a plain function.

Functions are mutable. You can see this in the following:
def foo():
    pass

foo.x = 1

Assigning to foo.x modifies the function object.
But copy.deepcopy() doesn't make a copy of functions.
bar = copy.deepcopy(foo)
print(id(foo) == id(bar)) # prints True

It's a simplification to say that deepcopy() makes a copy of all mutable objects. It's true for container types, but not for various system types.
While functions are mutable, we rarely use them as mutable containers. If you need to associate data with a function, you normally use a class; the data goes in instance variables, and the function can access them using self.attribute. Then you make a copy of the instance to get independent objects.

Does this mean if I want to have a deepcopy for my class A, I need to implement it myself rather than directly using copy.deepcopy()? I would like to have the ability to construct a deep copy of an instance of class A, and the new copy is completely independent from the original one.

Why do you need to modify the function? Assigning to _member_b is not modifying the function, it's modifying the A instance.
